# Disable a button in a x86 app by editing the executable

Tags: x86, vb6, decompiler

I have a x86 app (written in VB and compiled to x86 arch) and my students use (for various reasons) a ~2 year-old version, for which I no longer have the source code. I need to disable, in this old version, a button in the UI and I'm guessing the only way is to "edit" the compiled x86 assembly code by changing the current instructions to NOP for the click.

Could anyone please point me in the right direction of how to accomplish this:

- which editor to use
- how to find the correct place/instruction to change
- how to make the actual change

alternatively, please tell me if this is a fool's errand

p.s. a warning pop-up would be even better (after the click) but if that's way too complicated I'm happy with just a NOP

thank you

Comment: Perhaps create a small "launcher" program that would start up the old executable then call [`EnableWindow(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enablewindow) to disable the button?

Comment: Not sure if that's a road you'd want to go down, but there are [a couple of decompilers](http://www.program-transformation.org/Transform/VisualBasicDecompilers) for VB6 available.